# Multi-dimensional points in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, dimensions

I have experience in PostgreSQL but I am fresh new in PostGIS and I can see how quickly would I like it. I have extensively worked on time series and now I am discovering the spatial side of my data. I have installed PostGIS on my server and then I am wondering how to anwser tons of questions. Thus I am in the prospective part of my work and I have everything to learn.

Anyway, I would like to have some clues from GIS expert in order to take the good start. Basically, I am monitoring concentrations at constant places, but we also have some campaigns where we monitor concentrations when we are in motion. That is, we have, at least, a five dimension problem, spatial and time is tracked down by GPS and another dimensions are assessed by dedicated monitors.

I know that PostGIS have a multipoint object, but all example that I have seen on the web are limited to 4D. Is it possible to use this structure to store multiple concentrations in addition of space and time. If so, is there a simple way to get rid of extra dimensions such as concentrations and time, when we are just working on space? If I want to post process my data with QGIS, will I be able to use such structure?

Comment: Geometries as far as I know can have 2-4 dimensions: in addition to X and Y there can be either Z for height or M for one measure, or both. If you need more dimensions attach attributes to your geometries.

Comment: Normally, time would be a separate column, and you can store, x,y,z plus measure in the geometry. Is that not enough?

Comment: @ John Barça, what if I have many trajectories, will it be a table of points, I would like to have lines and then should I store time and concentrations in float[]?

Comment: What kind of queries are you going to be running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that PostGIS have a multipoint object, but all example that I have seen on the web are limited to 4D. **Is it possible to use this structure to store multiple concentrations in addition of space and time.** If so, is there a simple way to get rid of extra dimensions such as concentrations and time, when we are just working on space? If I want to post process my data with QGIS, will I be able to use such structure?

PostGIS supports up to four dimensions `(x,y,z,m)`. That is all. I suggest never using `m`. Instead, store these attributes on the table instead.

However, if you want to do this with [PostgreSQL and not PostGIS this answer may be of use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163915/2639).. Or at the least entertaining.

Answer (score 1):

In GIS, there is a concept for POINT, LINE and POLYGON (in a vector sense). There's no concept of LINE MADE OF POINTS, or SEQUENTIAL MULTI-POINT.

A multi-point dataset is simply many points grouped together with one set of attribute for the group.

For what you want to do, I think you just want to have something like:

```
id, station_id, datetime, geometry, observation_1, observation_2
```

If you want to display them together, you can style them by station_id, perhaps. You can also create a view that joins them into lines, to view a track, if that makes sense.

There is also a plugin for QGIS that does time-series visualisation (it does a real-time select based on a datetime range as you move a slider).

Comment: One could argue there is no concept of line in GIS; They're all linesegments inherently made of points. I'm not sure what a sequential multi-point is, but the *sequence* of points inside determine geometric equality and can be significant. For comparison there is a [native line type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html) (storing `Ax + By + C = 0`).

Comment: But, @EvanCarroll, a linesegment only has one set of attributes for the whole line feature. The vertices that make up the line don't have individual attributes (aside from x, y, (z, m)).